# Solidity: ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract /interface/library definition

Tags: node.js, ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I am getting error with both latest solc (0.5.2 version) and 0.4.25 too while I am writing Simple contract

I have tried following steps

1. uninstalled Solc: npm uninstall solc
2. Installed targeted version: npm install --save solc@0.4.25
3. node compile.js (code given below)

   ```
     { contracts: {},
     errors:
      [ ':1:1: ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract
    /interface/library definition.\nD:\\RND\\BlockChain\\contracts\\Inbox.sol\n^\n' ],sourceList: [ '' ],sources: {} }
   ```

**Compile.js**

```
const path  = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');
const inPath = path.resolve(__dirname,'contracts','Inbox.sol');
const src =  fs.readFileSync(inPath,'UTF-8');
const res = solc.compile(inPath, 1);

console.log(res);
```

**Inbox.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;

contract Inbox {
    string  message;


    function Inbox(string passedName) public {
        message = passedName;
    } 

    function setMessage(string newMsg) public {
        message = newMsg;
    }

    function getMessage() public view returns(string){
        return message;
    }
}
```

***Code worked well on Remix***, for version 0.5.2 I have added memory tag to make it compile on Remix.

```
ex:   function setMessage(string **memory** newMsg)
```

Answer (score 9):

This is not the case for you, but I'm going to leave this solution here for someone who may need this. I got this error when I forgot the semicolon ';' at the end of the first line `pragma solidity ^0.4.25;`. So be sure to check that.

Comment: My problem was with the spelling of `contract`. I was initially defining the `contract` by using a capital 'C' in the `contract` keyword; like this: `Contract`. The correct form is `contract`.

Answer (score 3):

### solc <= v0.4.25

Your primary issue using Solidity/solc **v0.4.25** is your constructor definition.

You currently have your constructor defined as:

```
function Inbox(string passedName) public
```

However, defining constructors with the same name as the contract has been deprecated in Solidity. Try defining your constructor using the `constructor` keyword instead.

```
 constructor(string passedName) public
```

If you are using solc **v0.4.25**, please refer to the [documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.25/using-the-compiler.html) in order to understand how to properly pass input to the `compile` function. See my reference below:

```
const input = { 
    'Inbox.sol': fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'Inbox.sol'), 'utf8') 
}
const output= solc.compile({sources: input}, 1);

if(output.errors) {
    output.errors.forEach(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
} else {
    const bytecode = output.contracts['Inbox.sol:Inbox'].bytecode;
    const abi = output.contracts['Inbox.sol:Inbox'].interface;
    console.log(`bytecode: ${bytecode}`);
    console.log(`abi: ${JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(abi), null, 2)}`);
}
```

### solc >= v0.5.0

If you are using Solidity/solc **v0.5.2**, you will also need to fix your `constructor` definition. Furthermore, you will need to add the `memory` keyword to each `function` that returns or accepts the `string` type.

For example:

```
function setMessage(string newMsg) public
```

should be declared as:

```
function setMessage(string memory newMsg) public
```

Futhermore, please see the [latest documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using-the-compiler.html) in order to understand the differences between the latest Solidity compiler and the older version. See my reference below for how to define the input for the `compile` function utilizing the latest compiler:

```
const input = { 
    language: "Solidity",
    sources: {
        "Inbox.sol": {
            content: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "contracts", "Inbox.sol"), "utf8") 
        }
    },
    settings: {
        outputSelection: {
            "*": {
                "*": [ "abi", "evm.bytecode" ]
            }
        }
    }
}
const output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));

if(output.errors) {
    output.errors.forEach(err => {
        console.log(err.formattedMessage);
    });
} else {
    const bytecode = output.contracts['Inbox.sol'].Inbox.evm.bytecode.object;
    const abi = output.contracts['Inbox.sol'].Inbox.abi;
    console.log(`bytecode: ${bytecode}`);
    console.log(`abi: ${JSON.stringify(abi, null, 2)}`);
}
```

Comment: thanks **Ben** for your time, as mentioned in my comment I have tired with v 5 too. For brevity I have added v4 code above. I still get the same error.

Comment: @yogeshsharma, please see my updated answer. I've included code samples for the older and latest versions of `solc`.

Comment: Thanks for your time and help. I will try this and let you know

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you've not save your contract in UTF-8 encoding.
to solve that you can open your contract file in a text editor and just save it as UTF8
(you can easily do it in VS code)

Comment: This solved for me. It was saved with "UTF-8 with BOM" encoding. I changed it to UTF-8 and it worked.

Comment: How do you change it in VSCode?

Answer (score 1):

Parse errors happen when you make an error in the syntax of your program.  I got the same error because

```
contract ERC721Enumerable is ERC721{

    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256){
        return _allTokens.length;
    }
// THIS WAS THE REASON
// this was closing contract and then outside of the contract i had function
}

    function _mint(address to, uint256 tokenId) internal override {
       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be using solc-js correctly. Please see the documentation: https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js

Specifically, you need to construct an input object and then stringify it and pass that to `solc.compile()`.

Comment: thanks **DAnsermino** for your time. I have tried using  as const res = solc.compile(JSON.stringify(inPath), 1);
But it still giving me **same error**

Comment: You can't just pass in the path, *you need to construct an import object*. why are you including the `1`? If you read the docs you will see the second argument is an optional parameter for an import callback.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your .sol file is encoded in UTF-8 without BOM.

Otherwise, convert to UTF-8.

I used Notepad++ to do that.

Encoding > Convert to UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not apply to you, but in my case, I got this error when there was an extra single curly bracket in my code. I just aligned all my curly brackets, removed the extra one and Voila! problem solved.