# ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library definition

Tags: javascript, compiler-errors, solidity

I got this error `"ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library definition"` everytime I use my `compile.js` with `node compile.js` command to compile my solidity file `Inbox.sol`. I've googled this error, there are two kinds of solutions, one is because of my syntax error, such as no `;`, the other is because of solidity compiler. I've check my solidity version and syntax, I can't find any error. Please help!

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53941422/solidity-parsererror-expected-pragma-import-directive-or-contract-interface) but it is not my solidity version, and if I change my code into `contructor`syntax, it will pops up error.

Inbox.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;
contract Inbox{
  string public message;
  function Inbox(string initialMessage)public{
    message = initialMessage;
  }
  function setMessage(string newMessage) public{
    message = newMessage;
  }

}
```

compile.js

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');

const inboxPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'Contracts','Inbox.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath,'utf8');

console.log(solc.compile(JSON.stringify({
    language: 'Solidity',
    sources: {
      'Inbox.sol': {
        content: source,
      },
    },
    settings: {
      outputSelection: {
        '*': {
          '*': ['evm', 'bytecode'],
        },
      },
    },
  })));
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "error",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "compile.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "solc": "^0.4.17"
  }
}
```

package-lock.json

```
"solc": {
      "version": "0.4.17",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/solc/-/solc-0.4.17.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-39Tmo2r+qclwW7ooLXMLzMSxmoGtHy3/p2sDKdA9NM/+MRtzLm/AFKj4BY2Cocg3gwkfJzKTEx6X0wiI4fIZ/A==",
      "requires": {
        "fs-extra": "^0.30.0",
        "memorystream": "^0.3.1",
        "require-from-string": "^1.1.0",
        "semver": "^5.3.0",
        "yargs": "^4.7.1"
      }
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my compile.js code into this

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');

const inboxPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'Contracts','Inbox.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath,'utf8');

console.log(solc.compile(source,1));
```

and then it works!!!